# Selenium Python using ActionChains

Tags: python, selenium

[image]The code I have opens a website and using actionChains, it right clicks on the desktop which brings up a menu.  I now need to do 3 more things with actionChains.  I need to hover over the item that says Save Page WE and then click an item on the sub-menu that pops up and then hit the enter button.  Can anyone show me how to do this? Thanks

```
from selenium import webdriver

    from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains
    fp = webdriver.FirefoxProfile('/Users/Jake/AppData/Roaming/Mozilla/Firefox/Profiles/emjx467y.default-1524932841911')
    driver = webdriv[enter link description here][1]er.Firefox(fp)
    driver.get('http://www.tradingview.com/screener')
    element = driver.find_element_by_link_text('Screener')
    actionChains = ActionChains(driver)
    actionChains.context_click(element).perform()
```

Comment: The screen shot refers to _Home Page_ og `http://www.google.com` where as your code trials refers to `http://www.tradingview.com/screener`. Questions seeking debugging help ("**Why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: also menu on screenshot is a browser menu, you can't interact with it in selenium

Comment: Kiril,  Isn't there a way to click on button using coordinates?  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

By using this line :  `actionChains.context_click(element).perform()` , you are trying to right click on **Screener** menu. But the ideal behavior should be to be **hover** on it and select one options out of 3.

I'm selecting **Forex Screener**, you can select any one as per your requirement.

For hover over you can try this code :

```
actionChains.move_to_element(element).perform()
```

Full code would be like this :

```
driver.get("http://www.tradingview.com/screener")  
wait = WebDriverWait(driver,40)

driver.find_element_by_css_selector("span[class*='tv-header__dropdown-wrap--noarrow'] span[class$='lang-icon--current-lang']").click()
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[text()='English (UK)']/parent::a"))).click()
element = driver.find_element_by_link_text('Screener')
actionChains = ActionChains(driver)
actionChains.move_to_element(element).perform()

wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.LINK_TEXT, "Forex Screener"))).click()
```

Make sure to import these :

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC 
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
```

Comment: What you did is pretty neat but unfortunately, not what I needed.  I need to click on an addon button using coordinates.